# Advanced Filter not determining lastrow correctly

Tags: excel, vba

This code works the way I want it, but there is this piece I am not understanding. The code consolidates data from multiple worksheets from multiple tables and pasted its own worksheet, then applies an advanced filter. The problem is the advanced filter code is not determining the last row with data correctly.

```
Worksheets("SummarySheet").Range("A18:G18" & Last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange _
  :=Worksheets("SummarySheet").Range("F3:G17"), Unique:=False
```

With the current data, the last row with data is on row 55. However, when I run the code in thinks the last row with data is on 1835. Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets2()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim Cell As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SummarySheet").ShowAllData

    ' Delete the data off of summary sheet.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SummarySheet").Range("A19:G19" & Last).Cells.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set DestSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SummarySheet")
        On Error Resume Next

        ' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
        ' summary worksheet.
        For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each tbl In sh.ListObjects
            For Each Cell In tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows

            If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

                ' Find the last row with data on the summary worksheet.
                Last = LastRow(DestSh)

                ' Specify the range to place the data. Select entire row where cells are orange.
                Set CopyRng = Cell

                ' Test to see whether there are enough rows in the summary
                ' worksheet to copy all the data.
                If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
                       "summary worksheet to place the data."
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                End If

                ' This statement copies values and formats from each
                ' worksheet.
                CopyRng.Copy
                With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End With
            End If
            Next
            Next
        Next

    Worksheets("SummarySheet").Range("A19:G19" & Last).Interior.ColorIndex = 0

    Worksheets("SummarySheet").Range("A19:G19" & Last).Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone


    Worksheets("SummarySheet").Range("A18:G18" & Last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange _
    :=Worksheets("SummarySheet").Range("F3:G17"), Unique:=False
    On Error Resume Next

    Worksheets("SummarySheet").Range("A3:A17").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    MsgBox "Done."

    ExitTheSub:

        Application.GoTo DestSh.Cells(1)

        ' AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
        DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the error is in this line:

```
Worksheets("SummarySheet").Range("A18:G18" & Last).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Worksheets("SummarySheet").Range("F3:G17"), Unique:=False
```

If *Last* was 99 then the range becomes `Range("A18:G1899)`. Just remove the **18** from **G18**.

```
Worksheets("SummarySheet").Range("A18:G" & Last).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Worksheets("SummarySheet").Range("F3:G17"), Unique:=False
```

But better as,

```
with Worksheets("SummarySheet") 
    .Range("A18:G" & Last).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=.Range("F3:G17"), Unique:=False
end with
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it had to be something simple.

Comment: [Glad to hear you got sorted out quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).